# Как выбрать элементы из базы, чтобы они ровно отображались в <div class="row"></div>?

Tags: bootstrap, jinja2

Получаю товары из БД, заполняю шаблон продуктами, а все эти продукты при помощи:

```
<div class="row">
{% include 'site/includes/featurette/featurette.html' %}
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что блоки получаются разной высоты, и они "пляшут"

Не совсем понимаю. Нужно делать выборку по 3 товара, и делать шаблон с тремя продуктами, а не с одним, или же это можно обыграть при помощи самого шаблона ? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Шаблон продукта:

```
{% for p in product %}
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      {% if p.image %}
        <img src="{{p.image}}" alt="{{p.name}}" style="width: 150%; height: 150%">
      {% endif %}

      {% if p.images %}
         <img src="{{(p.images[1:-1].split(',')[0])[1:-1]}}" alt="{{p.name}}" style="width: 150%; height: 150%">
      {% endif %}
      <div class="caption">
        <h4 style="text-align: center">{{p.name}}</h3>
        {% if p.size %}
        {% for i in p.size[1:-1].split("', '") %}
        <p>{{i}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}


        {% if p.specials %}

        <div class="table">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              {% if p.specials[0] == '[' %}
              {% for special in p.specials[1:-1].split(',') %}
                  <tr>
                    <td style="border-top: 0px">{{special.replace("'","")}}</td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
              {% for special in p.specials[1:-1].split(',') %}
              <!--p>{#{ special.replace("'", "")[0:6] }#}</p-->
              {% if special.replace("'", "")[0:6] =='Цвета:' %}
              {% elif special.replace("'", "")[0:6] == ' backg' %}
              {% elif special.replace("'", "")[0:6] == ' Цвета'%}
              {% else %}
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-top: 0px">{{ special.replace("'", "") }}</td>
                  <tr>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
        <p><span class="label label-{{ loop.cycle('success', '', 'danger') }} ">{{ loop.cycle('Скидка','', 'Акция') }}</span></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal" id="{{p.id}}" onclick="reply_click(this);">Заказать</a>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Получить скидку!</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: А Вам что в итоге надо-то? Чтобы блоки были одной высоты? Так и задайте им эту высоту + overflow: auto (если содержимое не будет помещаться в блок, то у блока появится полоса прокрутки). Это как вариант. Есть и другие.

Comment: Вообще, блоки с товарами пляшут, по причине того, что сколько бы их не было, они все в одном row, а для того, чтобы было по-правильному, нужно чтобы товары группировались в row, в моём случае, по 3 штуки. 
И я не совсем понимаю, выправлять это за счёт изменений в вёрстке и шаблоне, или же за счёт какой-то особой выборки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашёл здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797921/jinja2-create-new-row-for-every-3-items

В моём случае, решение оказалось таким:

```
{% for pr in product|batch(3, '&nbsp;') %}
  <div class="row">
  {% for p in pr if p.id %}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      {% if p.image %}
        <img src="{{p.image}}" alt="{{p.name}}" style="width: 150%; height: 150%">
      {% endif %}

      {% if p.images %}
         <img src="{{(p.images[1:-1].split(',')[0])[1:-1]}}" alt="{{p.name}}" style="width: 150%; height: 150%">
      {% endif %}
      <div class="caption">
        <h4 style="text-align: center">{{p.name}}</h3>
        {% if p.size %}
        {% for i in p.size[1:-1].split("', '") %}
        <p>{{i}}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}


        {% if p.specials %}

        <div class="table">
          <table class="table">
            <tbody>
              {% if p.specials[0] == '[' %}
              {% for special in p.specials[1:-1].split(',') %}
                  <tr>
                    <td style="border-top: 0px">{{special.replace("'","")}}</td>
                  </tr>
              {% endfor %}
              {% else %}
              {% for special in p.specials[1:-1].split(',') %}
              <!--p>{#{ special.replace("'", "")[0:6] }#}</p-->
              {% if special.replace("'", "")[0:6] =='Цвета:' %}
              {% elif special.replace("'", "")[0:6] == ' backg' %}
              {% elif special.replace("'", "")[0:6] == ' Цвета'%}
              {% else %}
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-top: 0px">{{ special.replace("'", "") }}</td>
                  <tr>
              {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              {% endif %}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
        <p><span class="label label-{{ loop.cycle('success', '', 'danger') }} ">{{ loop.cycle('Скидка','', 'Акция') }}</span></p>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product-modal" id="{{p.id}}" onclick="reply_click(this);">Заказать</a>
           <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">Получить скидку!</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```